# Google Sheet Reset and Move Tool Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need some help in creating a reset button(script) to reset a specific row and move the whole "patrol log" and "event log" tab into the "Archive" tab. If that is possible I would appreciate all help given. Here is my sheet, [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fhnEApTnKn-4gbX7RNaDB1Az7b48a1lGkbiL2JbEIiI/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

```
//attached reset to your button
function reset() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();//dont understand how you want to reset the row
  //sh.getRange(sh.getActiveCell().getRow(),1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).setValues(getResetValues());//dont know what to do with this
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const pl=ss.getSheetByName('patrol log');
  const el=ss.getSheetByName('event log');
  const as=ss.getSheetByName('Archive');
  let pv=pl.getRange(2,1,pl.getLastRow()-1,pl.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let ev=el.getRange(2,1,el.getLastRow()-1,el.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  if(as.getLastRow()>0) {
    as.getRange(as.getLastRow()+1,1,pv.length,pv[0].length).setValues(pv);
    as.getRange(as.getLastRow()+1,1,ev.length,ev[0].length).setValues(ev);
  }else{
    as.getRange(1,1,pv.length,pv[0].length).setValues(pv);
    as.getRange(as.getLastRow()+1,1,ev.length,ev[0].length).setValues(ev);
  }
  pl.getRange(2,1,pl.getLastRow()-1,pl.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  el.getRange(2,1,el.getLastRow()-1,el.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
}

//use to setup your row reset values
function getResetValues() {
  const ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const v=ps.getProperty('resetvalues');
  const rv=JSON.parse(v);
  return rv;
}

//gets your reset values
function setResetValues() {
  const ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const rA=[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]];//set this to whatever you want
  ps.setProperty('resetvalues', JSON.stringify(rA))
}
```